# Autocomplete C# code with object initialization syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, rider

When we are initializing objects intellisense suggests us autocompleting with `()`. Is there any way to autocomplete with `{}` rather than `()` in any kind of editor(Visual Studio or Rider)?

Comment: Do you mean typing `new Obje` completes to `new Object{}` instead of `new Object()`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes exactly! I have resharper by the way. I need to know how to trigger that.

Answer (score 0):

The object's constructor and its initializer are different things. Many classes have a default constructor without parameters. Autocomplete suggests calling it. If there is such a constructor, then before the initializer, you can not write the empty parentheses of this constructor.

Comment: You didn't get my point. I know what  all this means. I mean how can I autocomplete with `{}` rather than `()`. I am typing manually and it works. I need shortcut or something that autocompletes to `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can autocomplete to `{}` simply by typing `{` instead of using `TAB` or `Enter` buttons.

I'm using resharper, but it looks like it works even without it.